# php not opening file on mounted filesystem

Tags: php, file, splfileobject

I have the following bit of code that is giving me problems.

```
#$fullfilename="/data/extract/".$curpkg."/".$curfilename;
$fullfilename = "/tmp/test.txt";
$readline = 0;
$lictext="";
try {
     $file = new SplFileObject($fullfilename);
     $readline=$curline-1;
     while ($readline <= ($curline -1 + $curlinecount)) {
          $file->seek($readline);
          $lictext = $lictext . $file->current()."\n<br>";
          $readline = $readline + 1;
     }
} catch (Exception $e) {
     $lictext = "couldn't open it $fullfilename<br> Exception: $e<br>";
}
```

When I use the currently uncommented $fullfilename variable declaration, it works fine, but when I use the code that is commented out it does not.  I get the following error:

```
couldn't open it /data/extract/test.txt 
Exception:     exception 'RuntimeException' with message \
'SplFileObject::__construct(/data/extract/test.txt):\
failed to open stream: No such file or directory' in \
/srv/www/htdocs/legal/index.php:70
Stack trace:
#0 /srv/www/htdocs/legal/index.php(70): \
SplFileObject->__construct('/data/extract/test.txt')
```

The only difference is that the data I want to use is a separate drive mounted at /data. 
Permissions for the entire structure are 777: `drwxrwxrwx   2 root root 53248 Jan  7 14:31 data`.

I am at a loss here, I have the same problem with file_exists() and is_readable().  Can anyone give me some guidance here?

Comment: have you tried accessing in the shell? are you using some kind of links from /tmp to /data/extract?

Comment: and what about linking? (ln -sf or similar)

Comment: I've tried linking to files in it with the same result.

Comment: have you tried su - www-data -s/bin/bash (or apache) to access that file?

Comment: use strace and check what's system function is failing.

Comment: alright, time to eat dog crap.  there is a permissions issue I missed.  dangit.

Comment: The /data/exports directory was symlinked to a second level dir of a different mount.  That mount had restrictive permissions on it.  I added +x and now all is good.  My compliments to KikoV.